# Broken rowIndex parameter in R's XLSX package

Tags: r, package, xlsx

I noticed something odd today. I have a few scripts that I was using with my older version of R (2.15). I updated R a few weeks ago and I am running version 3.0.1.

I noticed that the xlsx package does not work as it did before:

E.g., I have an `xlsx` file that contains 20,000 lines, however, I only want to read the first 100 lines.

Previously

```
 myTable <- read.xlsx("myData.xlsx",    
    sheetIndex = 1, 
    rowIndex = 1:100,   
    colIndex = 1:3)
```

worked for me. However, now it is reading all 20,000 lines. Is it a bug or has something changed with the new release of R and this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the developer of this package and he confirmed that this was a bug indeed. He was also very quick about fixing it, the new version of the `xlsx` package (0.5.2) is available at

https://code.google.com/p/rexcel/